# Cast uint8_t to hex string (2 digits)

Tags: c

I'm currently using the following to print `uint8_t` to `hex`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    printf("%02X ", bytes[j]);
}
```

Is it possible to do this without a `for`-loop and simply assign the result to a variable?

Comment: C or C++? `std::cout << std::hex << value` in C++ but isn't valid C.

Comment: Sorry, in `C`. Adding to question.

Comment: If you have an array of bytes that you want to do something with (like print each byte), you need to use a loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: Is there an easy way to append to a string?

Comment: `strcat` or `sprintf` springs to mind.

Comment: But are they memory effecient? This loop would be run around 10-100 per second. Looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13738/ tells somethins of `sprintf, strcpy, strcat (and also strlen function) are all considered dangerous...`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a for loop?

Comment: I need to send the combined `HEX` `string` to a database.

Comment: "_are they memory effecient_" - Sort of. Using `sprintf` to convert to hex is not optimal, but is good enough for most applications. You can implement a faster one, like `iota`, yourself if you find `sprintf` too slow and that's not too hard.

Comment: @AlfredBalle People are taking the 'danger' thing too far. They are all dangerous if you are not in control of the string you pass to them or you haven't allocated a destination buffer that is large enough. Still, there should be size-limted 'safe' variants such as `strncpy` or `snprintf` available which you could use. It is very unlikely that you can write code for this yourself that is faster than any of these.

Comment: Please update your question to ask about the *real* problem you need to solve. What are you really trying to do? Are you printing the bytes? Are you creating a string containing the bytes? If creating a string, will you print it? Print the string immediately or later? Do you need to save the string for later?

Comment: "is it possible to do this without a for-loop and simply assign the result to a variable?" --> Yes - without a `for/while` loop.  Alfred Ballem, why do you not want to use a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool to_hex(char* dest, size_t dest_len, const uint8_t* values, size_t val_len) {
    if(dest_len < (val_len*2+1)) /* check that dest is large enough */
        return false;
    *dest = '\0'; /* in case val_len==0 */
    while(val_len--) {
        /* sprintf directly to where dest points */
        sprintf(dest, "%02X", *values);
        dest += 2;
        ++values;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    uint8_t values[256];
    char buf[sizeof(values)*2+1]; /* one extra for \0 */

    for(size_t i=0; i<256; ++i)
        values[i] = i;

    if(to_hex(buf, sizeof(buf), values, sizeof(values)))
        printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Output:

```
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
```

For completeness, here's a self contained version using a lookup table instead of `sprintf`:

```
bool to_hex(char* dest, size_t dest_len, const uint8_t* values, size_t val_len) {
    static const char hex_table[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    if(dest_len < (val_len*2+1)) /* check that dest is large enough */
        return false;
    while(val_len--) {
        /* shift down the top nibble and pick a char from the hex_table */
        *dest++ = hex_table[*values >> 4];
        /* extract the bottom nibble and pick a char from the hex_table */
        *dest++ = hex_table[*values++ & 0xF];
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Normally I get something like: `D4 CA 6D 8E 91 E4 F4 0F 24 0E 95 0B 08 00 45 00 00 54 21 BF 00 00 40 01 1E E9 C0 A8 14 E4 64 60 00 15 08 00 F1 29 B7 5B 00 00 5D 68 E1 92 00 0B 25 71 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37`. This gives me `D4CA6D8E91E4F40FF40F240E950BD4CA` So seems to be only parts.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're giving it the same input above. If you create `values` with a known input and compare the output with the expected. Does it look wrong?

Comment: I've run the functions next to eachother, and have following output:
```
    char buf[sizeof(bytes)*2+1]; /* one extra for \0 */
    if(to_hex(buf, sizeof(buf), bytes, sizeof(bytes))) {
        printf("Buffer: %s\n", buf);
    }

OUTPUT: D4CA6D8E91E4F40F

    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        printf("%02X ", bytes[j]);
    }

OUTPUT: D4 CA 6D 8E 91 E4 F4 0F 24 0E 95 0B 08 00 45 00 00 34 00 00 40 00 40 06 6B 1A C0 A8 14 E4 95 51 64 CC FD 83 7F 0E 94 92 D7 2A F6 DC 35 15 80 10 07 FF AC 5A 00 00 01 01 08 0A 0D E8 98 4D 0B 2D 2D 15
```

Comment: You are not passing the same arguments to the compared functions. `sizeof(bytes)` will not work if `bytes[]` has already passed through a function call (and decayed to a `char*`). In that case `sizeof(bytes)` will be the size of a pointer - which explains why you get 8 bytes as hex every time. 8 bytes is probably the size of a pointer on your system. Instead of `char buf[sizeof(bytes)*2+1];` do `char buf[len*2+1];`

Comment: Corner hole: `to_hex(dest, 256, values, 0) ` fails to insure `dest` points to a _string_.  Code could add `*dest = 0;`

Comment: My comment applies to first code.  I see 2nd has `*dest = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd go for the [sprintf approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57723618/3214247), but if you badly do not want to use one of the library api, you could use something like this:

```
char HexLookUp[] = "0123456789abcdef";    
void bytes2hex (unsigned char *src, char *out, int len)
{
    while(len--)
    {
        *out++ = HexLookUp[*src >> 4];
        *out++ = HexLookUp[*src & 0x0F];
        src++;
    }
    *out = 0;
}
```

Test code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    unsigned char bytes[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xCC};
    char buffer[sizeof(bytes)*2 + 1];
    bytes2hex(bytes, buffer, sizeof(bytes));
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 00010203deadbeefcc

Comment: Would the `sprintf` match the example given by Ted L.?

Comment: @AlfredBalle yes, it would be something like that. If your problem is the execution overhead associated with repeated calls to `sprintf`, you could use my version instead.

Comment: @AlfredBalle Added a solution using `sprintf` as well since you asked.

Comment: First solution does not have [this corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723372/cast-uint8-t-to-hex-string-2-digits#comment101895482_57723618) problem.  2nd one does.